# Issue with NSDictionary from swift to Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

I have a code in swift and try to understand and convert it to the objective c , here is the code :

```
func connectionDidFinish(Identifier: String) {
    let count:Int = (data.DictonaryData["actions"]?.allKeys.count)! + (data.DictonaryData["files"]?.allKeys.count)!
    ResultsCount_Lable.text = String(count) + " Results"
}
```

So far I know `allKeys.count` is property of NSArray , does this code try to get a key from `NSDictionary` ?

Is this right code according to that swift code :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinish:(NSString *)string {
   NSDictionary *filesDict = [data.dictonaryData objectForKey:@"files"];
   NSArray *array = [filesDict allKeys];
   int count = array.count;
}
```

Comment: Well you don't have all of your "action" keys part of your dictionary, but you did the `filesDict` right. Looks like the answer below shows you how to get a count for both. Pretty much just do what you did for `filesDict` but also for action keys and add the sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below code from Swift to Objective C.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinish:(NSString *)Identifier {

    NSDictionary *actionDict = [data.dictonaryData objectForKey:@"actions"];
    NSDictionary *filesDict = [data.dictonaryData objectForKey:@"files"];
    NSInteger count = actionDict.allKeys.count + filesDict.allKeys.count;

    ResultsCount_Lable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Results",(long)count];

}
```

Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: Wrong answer ! `data.DictonaryData[@"actions"].allKeys.count` is not an objective c code

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I had updated my answer please check it.

Comment: It is my pleasure. If it is make sense then please accept my answer.